# How do I make public for download files owned by the s3-log-service?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've created a bucket to hold the log files created by the s3-log-service, and I've made the permissions so that the bucket can be both listed and the contents are publically accessible.  I can list the contents of the bucket but web access to a log is denied with a 403 error.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    }
  ]
}
```

I gather such a policy doesn't work when the object (log file) is owned by someone else.

So, what other permissions do I need to apply to the bucket contents to make them publically accessible?

Comment: [similar question from 2011](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=242511&#242511) on amazon forums, unanswered.

Comment: Why would you want to make your log files public?  It seems like you may actually be trying to solve a different problem than the one you're describing here?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in saying that the bucket policy does not apply to objects not owned by the AWS account. You have 2 options:

1. You'll need to copy the objects onto themselves, setting the ACL flag to `public-read`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX \
aws s3 cp \
    s3://BUCKET/OBJECT_PATH \
    s3://BUCKET/OBJECT_PATH \
    --acl public-read
```

2. Set the ACL flag to `bucket-owner-full-control`. From there, the bucket policy take over objects' permissions.

The only way I found to do either option (without getting access denied errors) is to use the AWS account root user's credentials.